# Why won't jQuery remove my class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, validation, jquery-selectors

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xrjsq6Ls/

I can't seem to have jQuery remove the class I specify, however fadeOut() will fadeOut the intended DOM element. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="comment_section">
    <div class="comment_outter user-marked-offensive">
        <div class="comment_arrows"></div>
        <div class="comment_inner">
            <div class="actions"> 
                <a class="offensive simulate-link">Mark Comment As Offensive</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var selector = ".user-marked-offensive > .comment_inner > .actions > .offensive";

$('.comment_section').on("mouseover", selector, function () {
    $(this).closest('.comment_outter').removeClass('.user-marked-offensive');
    //$(this).closest('.comment_outter').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Try to remove '.' in removeClass('user-marked-offensive')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) takes a class name as the parameter not a class selector

```
$(this).closest('.comment_outter').removeClass('user-marked-offensive');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e8gL0mgx/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You should remove `.` in `removeClass` method

```
$(this).closest('.comment_outter').removeClass('.user-marked-offensive');
```

to

```
$(this).closest('.comment_outter').removeClass('user-marked-offensive');
```

Answer (score 1):

with removeClass you don't need to write the dot before the name of the class ;)

```
$(this).closest('.comment_outter').removeClass('user-marked-offensive');
```